# How to display weather properly with conky?

Tags: themes, 23.10, conky, widgets

I have problem with a theme in conky and, more specifically, with a conky widget. The theme is called "alsafi" and it works properly, but the weather widget by default shows the weather of Bologna (Italy). I changed the API key and city ID in `~/.config/conky/Alsafi/scripts/weather2.sh`, but it still shows Bologna even after rebooting and restarting conky. What can the issue be?

**Note**: the theme runs from conky manager 2 so the location is `~/.conky`.

the edited files: weather-v2.0.sh

```bash
# This script is to get weather data from openweathermap.com in the form of a json file
# so that conky will still display the weather when offline even though it doesn't up to date

# Variables
# get your city id at https://openweathermap.org/find and replace
city_id=256639 #<---modified to display my city 

# replace with yours
api_key=c99cf91646e0ca8d6ff63957a1d20552 #<--- personal api key

# choose between metric for Celcius or imperial for fahrenheit
unit=metric

# i'm not sure it will support all languange, 
lang=en

# Main command
url="api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${city_id}&appid=${api_key}&cnt=5&units=${unit}&lang=${lang}"
curl ${url} -s -o ~/.cache/weather.json

exit
```

After running `grep -iRE 'Alsafi|weather.sh' ~/.conky ~/.config/conky` the output of terminal is:

```
/home/kr/.conky/Sirius/Changelog:-  New Weather.sh
/home/kr/.conky/conky-startup.sh:cd "$HOME/.conky/Alsafi"
/home/kr/.conky/conky-startup.sh:conky -c "$HOME/.conky/Alsafi/Alsafi.conf" &
/home/kr/.conky/Alsafi/Changelog:Alsafi - Conky Theme
/home/kr/.conky/Alsafi/Alsafi.conf:--  ALSAFI
/home/kr/.conky/Alsafi/Alsafi.conf:${execi 600 ~/.config/conky/Alsafi/scripts/weather-v2.0.sh}\
/home/kr/.conky/Alsafi/Alsafi.conf:${offset 0}${voffset 10}${color}${font feather:size=20}${execi 15 ~/.config/conky/Alsafi/scripts/weather-text-icon}${goto 73}${font}
/home/kr/.conky/Alsafi/Alsafi.conf:${offset 0}${voffset 0}${color1}${font Barlow:bold:size=13}${exec ~/.config/conky/Alsafi/scripts/playerctl.sh}
/home/kr/.conky/Alsafi/Alsafi.conf:${offset 0}${voffset 0}${font Barlow:bold:size=10}Wi-Fi : ${execi 5 ~/.config/conky/Alsafi/scripts/ssid}
/home/kr/.conky/Alsafi/start.sh:conky -c $HOME/.config/conky/Alsafi/Alsafi.conf &> /dev/null &
/home/kr/.config/conky/Sirius/Changelog:-   New Weather.sh
```

Ok so after restarting conky thas the cache with weather.json

```
➜  ~ cat ~/.cache/weather.json     
{"coord":{"lon":11.4333,"lat":44.4667},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":11.95,"feels_like":11.66,"temp_min":10.77,"temp_max":13.14,"pressure":1016,"humidity":94},"visibility":7000,"wind":{"speed":3.09,"deg":40},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1709155681,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2004497,"country":"IT","sunrise":1709099691,"sunset":1709139562},"timezone":3600,"id":3181927,"name":"Bologna","cod":200}
```

So finally after more research the issue solved.The cause are the permissions .The weather.json file has permission to write and read from me but not from other apps so it couldnt get the data from the api .After changing the permissions using gui the issue solve.Thanks for your time and your help i really appreciate that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your conky configuration file. Also show us this `weather2.sh` file. Just copy/paste them into your question and then use the `{}` button on the editor to mark them as code.

Comment: Just one more detail .could you define me what configuration file you need?

Comment: The `weather.sh` file and whatever other file you have edited in order to use it. There should be a `~/.conkyrc` file or a `~/.config/conky/conky.conf` file (`~/` means your home directory), check which one you have and add it to the question.

Comment: ok so i updated my post question with the code that i modified .the variables i modifies ("if variable is the correct term") have been highlightened to you by # followed by an arrow (#<---)

Comment: OK, but somewhere, there must be a file that tells conky to run this. Is there nothing in `~/.config/conky/`? Or maybe you have files in `~/.conky`? Is that a file or a directory? What is the output for `grep -iRE 'Alsafi|weather.sh' ~/.conky ~/.config/conky`?

Comment: Ah, also, try deleting `~/.cache/weather.json` (`rm ~/.cache/weather.json`) and then restarting conky. Does that help?

Comment: This is weird. We need to also see the contents of `~/.cache/weather.json`, what do you see there after restarting conky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems the issue is on `~/.cache/weather.json` .
What I did was change the permissions for other apps to write and read to the file. This can be done from the terminal by typing :

```
chmod o+w ~/.cache/weather.json
```

Comment: Perhaps `chmod o+w ~/.cache/weather.json` in the terminal would do the same thing? Could you add a screenshot of the Properties > Permissions Tab for `~/.cache/weather.json`? That will make the answer 100 percent better for anyone else with the same problem.